# Flash CS5, dynamic text field strips out certain letters

Tags: flash, text, flash-cs5

Using CS5, and certain letters simply won't show up in my dynamic text field.  Not even a blank shows up, they just get stripped out.  'g' and 'v' are two of the letters, so the string 'v testing' shows up on the stage as 'testin'.

It doesn't seem to matter if I start with the string already in there, or add it dynamically.  Here are the settings, but they don't really seem to matter either, I've experimented:

Classic Text
Dynamic Text
Ariel 
Regular
Anti-alias for animation
Single line

Anyone seen this?  Is it a font issue?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you have where you create the TextField and assign the property values?

Comment: Are you embedding characters or does this occur regardless of the font? Arial is a web standard font so you may just try using the "use device fonts" anti-alias setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This most definitely is a font embedding issue. I've found that even when you specify in Flash CS5 to NOT embed the font, it will still embed any characters that are used in textfields using that font. So that may be the reason why only certain characters appear (those are the characters that were in the textfield when you published the swf). Click the "Embed..." button in FlashCS5 to really embed the font. Check the character ranges you need and you should be good to go again.

Font embedding is one of the struggles that I keep facing in different situations and still don't have one solution that fits all use cases.

Comment: Indeed, embedding fixes it.  I thought I had tried that.  Still, this is the first time I've run into this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem even with embedded fonts (Arial and Helvetica). As well as the above by frankhermes, you must also do the following;

SOLUTION:

Ensure that your external file being loaded dynamically is also supported; in my case a text file.
To ensure a text file is supported when loading text with foreign characters into a dynamic text field in Flash, make sure you save it as a UTF-8 Unicode.

METHOD:

Whilst in Text Edit, click FILE > SAVE AS, name your file and at the bottom of the Save As dialoue box, you will see "Plain Text Encoding" with a drop down list next to it, click the drop-down and choose "Unicode (UTF-8)" and then save it.

Viola! Problem solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a label instead of dynamic text and you'll be fine.

Solution: go to => Window => Components => and drag in a label then set the instance name and use it dynamically by setting its text property.

I hope this helps.

Cheers..!!